# Print double without printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to display a double without printf or all other libs except stdlib.h for malloc.
I know how the double is stocked and i'm experiencing issues with the calcul.

I know double is stocked in 64 bits :

- 1 for the sign;
- 11 for the exponent;
- 52 for the value;

I used some conversions to get all those values, and i'm failing on getting the 1.fraction (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), i get the mantisma, but i don't know how to add correctly this 1.
here some code :

```
double              d;
unsigned long long  *double_as_int;
unsigned long long  value;

d = 0.5;
double_as_int = (unsigned long long *)&d;
value = *double_as_int & 0x001FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
printf("value = %llu\n", value); /* <- just for verification */
```

i already know that to get the mantisma i need to do only `0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFULL` but i'm trying to add the one in the 1.fraction part.
do you guys have any idea how to resolve this part?

Comment: I'd suggest you not cast a `double *` to an `unsigned long long *`. Not only could they be of different sizes, but I believe due to strict aliasing this is actually undefined behavior. Use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: The exponent sets the value of the implicit 1 bit. For example, if the exponent is 1027, then the 1 bit has a value of 16 (since the exponent is offset by 1023). And the bits of the mantissa, starting with the MSB have weights 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, and so on. For example, if the exponent is 1027, and the first 8 bits of the mantissa are 00101100 and the other bits of the mantissa are 0, then your number is 16 + 2 + 0.5 + 0.25 = 18.75

Comment: You can use union punning to convert the double to the appropriate sized int without undefined behavior (and without using the stdlib).

Answer (score 1):

> I know double is stocked in 64 bits

Not necessarily. A "IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point" number is stocked in 64-bits. A "double" may be anything, it may not and it may follow IEEE 745 standard. You should check `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro before assuming it is [C11 Annex F](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.1).

If you want to manipulate floating point numbers, you should use `frexp` and other such functions specifically meant to abstractly manipulate the representation of floating point numbers, without any `*(super unsafe casts*)`:

```
double d = DBL_MIN / 2;
int exponent;
double fraction = frexp(d, &exponent);
if (fraction == 0 && exponent == 0) abort(); /*handle error*/
printf("%g = %d * 2^%d * %f\n", d, d<0?-1:1, exponent, fraction);
```

> how to resolve this part?

The `1.fraction` represents a fractional number like `1.01010111..` *in base-2*. The **digits** after comma are just the bits in the fraction part of the floating point number, in order. The following program (with many bugs in it) is meant to output the floating point value in the representation in the form `sign * 2^(exp) * [0/1].fraction(2)`, where fraction is in base-2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#if !__STDC_IEC_559__
#error
#endif
int main() {
    double d = DBL_MIN / 2;

    typedef union {
        unsigned long long sign : 1;
        unsigned long long exp : 11;
        unsigned long long fract : 52;
    } double64u;
    double64u di;
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(double64u), "");
    memcpy(&di, &d, sizeof(double));

    // extract **binary** digits from value into buffer
    char buffer[53] = {0};
    char *p = buffer + 52;
    unsigned long long tmp = di.fract;
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i) {
        *(--p) = (tmp & 0x1) + '0';
        tmp >>= 1;
    }

    char sign = di.sign < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    
    bool normal = di.exp != 0;

    printf("%g = \n", d);
    if (normal) {
        printf("%d * 2^(%d - 1023) * 1.%s(2)\n",
            sign, di.exp, buffer);
    } else {
        printf("%d * 2^(1 - 1023) * 0.%s(2)\n",
            sign, buffer);
    }
}
```

On my x86-64 this program outputs:

```
1.11254e-308
1 * 2^(1 - 1023) * 0.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000(2)
```

You can then take the `0.10..` which is a **base 2** number (so I added the `(2)` on the end) to some "binary to decimal converter", like [rapidtables](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html), and `0.1` in base-2 is `0.5` in base-10 (well, this example is simple anyway). So the number is:

```
 1 * 2^(1 - 1023) * 0.5
```

which then you can use some unlimited calculator like `bc` and input the number to calculate the actual result:

```
$ bc
scale=400
1 * 2^(1 - 1023) * 0.5
.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000011125369292536006915451163586662\
0203210960799023116591527666370844360221740695909792714157950
```

which is the same number as `1.11254e-308`.

Printing floating point numbers yourself is a **very** hard job to do. I can recommend https://www.ryanjuckett.com/printing-floating-point-numbers/ and papers that introduced Grisu3 and Ryu and Errol1 algorithms. For inspiration, read code from existing implementations: [newlib vfprintf.c cvt()](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c#L1798), [musl vfprintf.c fmt_fp()](https://github.com/bpowers/musl/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c#L206), [glibc printf_*fp_* stuff](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/printf_fp.c#L205).

Comment: thanks for your answer and your time, i'm working on it. It's a school work (recode printf, the double gestion is a bonus part). I guess the hard part is when we touch to the limits parts between 0, will see!